# Остановка игры pygame при достижении объектами низа экрана

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп, разработка-игр, pygame

Смысл этой игры заключается в том, чтобы отстреливать вражеские корабли, что по сути бесконечный процесс, по этому нужно добавить условие проигрыша. Оно заключается в том, что после того, как враги достигнут низа экрана, игра должна остановиться, а пули и враги исчезнуть с экрана. Через пару секунд все должно опять возобновиться
[image: вот пример игрового окна]

```py
import pygame
import sys
from pygame.sprite import Group

pygame.init()

# параметры экрана
height, width = 800, 650  # высота  # ширина
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))


# игрок
class Ship:
    def __init__(self, screen):
        self.screen = screen
        self.screen_rect = screen.get_rect()
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(300, 710, 80, 80)#создание прямоугольника игрока
        self.color = (255, 255, 255)

        self.move_left = False #переменные, отвечающие за передвижение
        self.move_right = False

    def move(self):
        if self.move_left == True: #условие присвоение значений True/False происходит в основном игровом цикле
            self.rect.centerx -= 1
        elif self.move_right == True:
            self.rect.centerx += 1
        if self.rect.right >= 650:
            self.rect.right = 650
        elif self.rect.left <= 0:
            self.rect.left = 0

    def output_s(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, self.color, self.rect)


# пули
class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, screen, my_ship):
        super(Bullet, self).__init__()
        self.screen = screen
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, 100, 10) #создание прямоугольника-пули
        self.speed = 5
        self.rect.centerx = my_ship.rect.centerx#координаты появления пули
        self.rect.top = my_ship.rect.top
        self.y = self.rect.y

    def update(self):
        """перемещение пули вверх"""
        self.y -= self.speed
        self.rect.y = self.y

    def draw_bullet(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, (255, 255, 255), self.rect)


# враги
class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):  # класс enemy наследник класса sprite
    def __init__(self, screen):
        super(Enemy, self).__init__()
        self.screen = screen
        self.screen_rect = screen.get_rect()
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, 70, 70)
        self.rect.top = self.screen_rect.top
        self.rect.centerx = self.screen_rect.centerx
        self.x = float(self.rect.x)
        self.y = float(self.rect.y)

    def output_e(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, (255, 255, 255), self.rect)

    def update(self):
        self.y += 0.1
        self.rect.y = self.y


# объекты классов и группы
my_ship = Ship(screen)
bullets = Group()
enemys = Group()

# создания ряда врагов
def create_enemy(screen, enemys, width):
    enemy_width = Enemy(screen).rect.width
    e_numbers = (width - 50) // enemy_width #количество врагов в ряду
    for i in range(e_numbers):
        enemy = Enemy(screen)
        enemy.x = 25 + (enemy_width + 25) * i #расстояние каждого корабля друг от друга(от экрана)
        enemy.rect.x = enemy.x
        enemys.add(enemy) #добавление в ряд-группу одного корабля


# движение пуль и их столконовение с врагами
def update_bullets(bullets, enemys):
    bullets.update()#перемещение пули вверх
    collision = pygame.sprite.groupcollide(bullets, enemys, True, True) #столкновение пули и врага
    for bullet in bullets.copy():
        if bullet.rect.bottom <= 0:
            bullets.remove(bullet) #удаление пули, вышедшей за пределы экрана


# отрисовка пуль, игрока и врагов на экране
def screen_update(screen, enemys, bullets):
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0)) #заливка экрана
    for enemy in enemys:
        enemy.output_e() #вывод каждого врага на экран
    for bullet in bullets:
        bullet.draw_bullet() #отрисовка пули
    my_ship.output_s() #отображение игрока
    my_ship.move() #вызов метода передвижения игрока
    pygame.display.flip()

#ИГРОВОЙ ЦИКЛ
def main():
    create_enemy(screen, enemys, width)  # Создаем первый врагов при старте
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                    my_ship.move_left = True
                elif event.key == pygame.K_d:
                    my_ship.move_right = True
                # стрельба, создание новой пули при нажатии пробела
                elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:

                    new_bullet = Bullet(screen, my_ship)
                    bullets.add(new_bullet)

            elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                    my_ship.move_left = False
                elif event.key == pygame.K_d:
                    my_ship.move_right = False


        # создание рядов, следующих друг за другом
        last_enemy = enemys.sprites()[-1]#отслеживание последего появившегося ряда
        if enemys and last_enemy.rect.y >= 100:
            create_enemy(screen, enemys, width)

        enemys.update() #движение врагов
        update_bullets(bullets, enemys) #перемещение и столкновение пули
        screen_update(screen, enemys, bullets) #отрисовка объектов на экране и его обновление


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему.

Answer (score 0):

Я не обнаружил в приведенном вами примере того что вы пишите, т.е. у меня при достижении нижней границы экрана, начинается новая игра и вверху рисуется новый ряд врагов. Может я чего-то не так понял.

Я вам предложу проверить другой вариант похожей и более продвинутой игры.

Обратите внимание:

- движение игрока реализовано под левую и под правую руку;
- в игре реализован подсчет баллов и уровни игры;
- игра заканчивается при столкновении игрока с врагом;
- ...

Надеюсь пример будет полезет для вас.

```
import random
import time
import pygame
import pygame.mixer
from pygame.locals import *


class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
# --------------------------------------> vvvvvvvvvvvvvvv <------- установите свое
        self.images = [pygame.image.load("img/player1.png").convert_alpha(),
                       pygame.image.load("img/player2.png").convert_alpha()]

        self.current_image = 0
        self.speed = 20
# ------------------------------------> vvvvvvvvvvvvvvv <------- установите свое
        self.image = pygame.image.load("img/player1.png").convert_alpha()
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (68, 78))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect[0] = 600
        self.rect[1] = 510
        self.points = 0

    def update(self):
        self.animation()

    def animation(self):
        self.current_image = (self.current_image + 1) % 2
        self.image = self.images[self.current_image]
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (68, 78))


class Shot(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
# ------------------------------------> vvvvvvvvvvvv <--------------- установите свое
        self.image = pygame.image.load("img/shot.png").convert_alpha()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.speed = 30

    def update(self):
        self.rect[1] -= self.speed


class Enemy (pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
# -----------------------------------------> vvvvvvvvvvvvvvv <------- установите свое
        self.animation = [pygame.image.load("img/meteor1.png").convert_alpha(),
                          pygame.image.load("img/meteor2.png").convert_alpha(),
                          pygame.image.load("img/meteor3.png").convert_alpha()]
# ------------------------------------> vvvvvvvvvvvvvvv <------------- установите свое
        self.image = pygame.image.load("img/meteor1.png").convert_alpha()
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (68, 78))
        self.rect  = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect[0] = random.randint(10, 1100)
        self.rect[1] = random.randint(10, 30)
        self.speed = 1
        self.current_image = 0
        self.current_explosion = 0

    def update(self):
        self.current_image = (self.current_image + 1) % 3
        self.image = self.animation[self.current_image]
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (68, 78))
        self.rect[1] += self.speed
        

class Game():
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.init()                                     # инициализировать pygame
        # переменная, которая контролирует, запускается игра или нет
        self.game_start = True 

        self.window_width = 1200                          # ширина окна
        self.window_height = 600                          # высота окна

        # создает окно, передавая ширину и высоту в качестве параметров
        self.window = pygame.display.set_mode((self.window_width, self.window_height)) 
# -----------------------------------------> vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv <------ установите свое
        self.background = pygame.image.load("img/background.jpg") # фоновое изображение
        # определил ширину и высоту фонового изображения.
        self.background = pygame.transform.scale(
            self.background, (self.window_width, self.window_height)) 

        # Игрок
        self.player_group = pygame.sprite.Group()          # создает группу для игрока
        self.player = Player()                             # создать игрока
        self.player_group.add(self.player)                 # добавить игрока в группу
        self.player_right = False          # инициализирует переменную движения FALSE
        self.player_left = False           # инициализирует переменную движения FALSE

        # Выстрелил
        self.shoot_group = pygame.sprite.Group()           # создать группу выстрелов

        # Враг
        self.create_enemy = True
        self.enemy_group = pygame.sprite.Group()

        # !!! ОЧКИ И ИНФОРМАЦИЯ ОБ УРОВНЕ
        self.player_points = self.player.points
# ----------------------------------> vvvvvvvvvvvvv <--------------- установите свое        
        self.font = pygame.font.Font("font/8bit.ttf", 30)
        self.points_text = self.font.render("SCORE: " + str(self.player_points), 
            1, (255,255,255))
        self.level = 0
        self.enemy_in_window = 5
        self.level_text = self.font.render("LEVEL: "+ str(self.level), 
            1, (255, 255, 255))


        # ФОНОВАЯ МУЗЫКА
        pygame.mixer.init()
        pygame.mixer.set_reserved(0)
# ------------------------------------------> vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv <--- установите свое
        self.game_music = pygame.mixer.Sound("sounds/game_music.wav")
        pygame.mixer.Channel(0).play(self.game_music, -1)

        # FPS
        self.fps = pygame.time.Clock() # добавить часы в переменную для управления fps

        # ГЛАВНЫЙ ЦИКЛ
        self.game_init = True
        while self.game_init:
            self.fps.tick(30)                              # установите частоту кадров в игре
            for event in pygame.event.get():               # событие для игровых команд
                if event.type == QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()

                if event.type == KEYDOWN:                  # когда клавиша нажата
                    if event.key == K_d or event.key == K_RIGHT:
                        self.player_right = True
                    if event.key == K_a or event.key == K_LEFT:
                        self.player_left = True
                    if event.key == K_SPACE:               # кнопка для стрельбы
                        self.player_shot = Shot()          # 
                        self.player_shot.rect[0] = self.player.rect[0]+23 # передает начальную позицию по x
                        self.player_shot.rect[1] = self.player.rect[1]    # передает начальную позицию в y
                        self.shoot_group.add(self.player_shot)            # добавить кадр в группу кадров
                        pygame.mixer.Channel(1).play(pygame.mixer.Sound("sounds/shot.wav")) # огнестрельная музыка

                if event.type == KEYUP:                     # когда отпустишь клавишу
                    if event.key == K_d or event.key == K_RIGHT:
                        self.player_right = False
                    if event.key == K_a or event.key == K_LEFT:
                        self.player_left = False

            if self.player_right:             # если условие истинно, игрок движется вправо
                self.player.rect[0] += self.player.speed
            if self.player_left:              # если условие истинно, игрок движется влево
                self.player.rect[0] -= self.player.speed

            self.window.blit(self.background, (0, 0))            # нарисовать фон
            self.window.blit(self.points_text, (850, 10))        # счет
            self.window.blit(self.level_text, (650, 10))
            self.shoot_group.update()  # вызывает функцию обновления для всех в группе снимков
            self.player_group.update() # вызывает функцию обновления для всех в группе игрока
            self.player_group.draw(self.window) # рисует всю группу игроков на экране
            self.enemy_group.update()          # Вызов обновления группы противника
            self.enemy_group.draw(self.window) # рисовать врагов на экране

            if len(self.enemy_group) < 5: # Если у вас меньше 5 врагов, добавьте больше врагов.
                for i in range(5):
                    self.enemy = Enemy()
                    self.enemy_group.add(self.enemy)
                    print("Добавил еще одного врага")
# !!!
            if self.enemy.rect[1] > 600: # Когда враги достигают 700 пикселей экрана, они уничтожаются.
                self.enemy_group.remove(self.enemy)
                print("\nВраг покинул экран\n")
# !!!
            # ПРОВЕРКА СЧЕТА И УРОВНЯ
            if self.player_points > 500:
                self.enemy.speed  = 2
                self.level = 1
                self.level_text = self.font.render(
                    "LEVEL: "+ str(self.level), 1, (255, 255, 255))
            if self.player_points > 2000:
                self.enemy.speed  = 3
                self.level = 2
                self.level_text = self.font.render("LEVEL: "+ str(self.level),1,(255,255,255))
            if self.player_points > 4000:
                self.enemy.speed  = 4
                self.level = 3
                self.level_text = self.font.render("LEVEL: "+ str(self.level),1,(255,255,255))
            if self.player_points > 8000:
                self.enemy.speed  = 6
                self.level = 4
                self.level_text = self.font.render("LEVEL: "+ str(self.level),1,(255,255,255))
            if self.player_points > 10000:
                self.enemy.speed  = 8
                self.level = 5
                self.level_text = self.font.render("LEVEL: "+ str(self.level),1,(255,255,255))
            if self.player_points > 20000:
                self.enemy.speed  = 9
                self.level = 6
                self.level_text = self.font.render("LEVEL: "+ str(self.level),1,(255,255,255))
            if self.player_points > 50000:
                self.enemy.speed  = 12
                self.level = "FINAL LEVEL"
                self.level_text = self.font.render("LEVEL: "+ str(self.level),1,(255,255,255))

            for bullet in self.shoot_group: # для каждого кадра, находящегося в группе выстрелов
                self.shoot_group.draw(self.window)  # нарисуй кадр на экране
                if self.player_shot.rect[1] < -20:  # проверяет, меньше ли y-позиция кадра - 20 и в этом случае он уже покинул экран
                    self.shoot_group.remove(self.player_shot) # если проверка верна, то этот выстрел исключается из группы снимков
# !!!
            # ПРОВЕРКА СТОЛКНОВЕНИЙ
            if (pygame.sprite.groupcollide(self.shoot_group, self.enemy_group, True, True)):
                self.player_points += random.randint(1, 10)
                self.points_text = self.font.render("SCORE: " + str(self.player_points), 1, (255,255,255))
# ---  установите свое  ---------------------------------------> vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv <--- 
                pygame.mixer.Channel(2).play(pygame.mixer.Sound("sounds/enemy_death.wav")) # музыка смерти врага

            if (pygame.sprite.groupcollide(self.player_group, self.enemy_group, True, False)):
                    print(f'\nСтолкновение, новая игра \n') # 
                    Game()
                    self.game_init = False
            pygame.display.update()
            
Game()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**background.jpg**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**shot.png**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**player1.png**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**meteor1.png**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, отредактирую код, основываясь на вашем примере

Comment: @Wylon пожалуйста.  Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: А у вас похожая проблема. Если в верхней части экрана отстреливать метеориты во время того, как хотя бы один метеорит уходит за нижнюю, метеоры после продолжают спавниться. То есть даже если метеор уходит за границу экрана, игра продолжается. Я отредактирую свой вопрос, в силу чего лучше будет видна моя проблема

Comment: И мне нужна немного другая логика появления. У вас метеоры появляются, если их количество меньше определенного числа, а это не всегда корректно работает. Мне нужно, чтобы следующий ряд врагов появлялся, если предыдущий достиг определенной координаты экрана.